# Has anybody ever met `disable_shared_gems` error with RoR and Gitlab-CI?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, gitlab-ci

The error:

```
path:
Set for your local app (/usr/local/bundle/config): "vendor/bundle"

path.system:
Set via BUNDLE_PATH__SYSTEM: true

disable_shared_gems:
You have not configured a value for 'disable_shared_gems'
```

Appears only in GitLab-Ci pipline, in deps install stage.
Locally everything is ok.

Comment: I get this error too. Don't yet know how to fix it. I will check here if someone solves it or if I am able to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to issue in bundler and that version. they have a issue for it on github: https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/issues/288

Probably solved soon.